# JQuery Adding the percentage of a Div value to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using JQuery, I am trying to set the percentage of a div's id value and write it to another div.

Here is my current code...

```
  $("#percentage").text(
    parseFloat($("#total").text(percentage calculation here?))
    );
```

So, if #capacity had a value of 100 and #total had a value of 10 then the value of #percentage would be 10

How can I get this result?

Hope this makes sense

Comment: When you say `div's id value` do you mean `<div id="thing">20</div>` = `20`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#percentage").text(function() {
    var result = (parseInt($("#capacity").text(), 10) / parseInt($("#total").text(), 10));
    if (!isFinite(result)) result = 0;
    return result;
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/baVVf/1/)

Comment: That was so quick. I barely had time to get to the 2nd parseInt.

Comment: Although that will result in an exception if `total` = `0`

Comment: @LeeTaylor - should account for infinity and beyond now ?